# jquery history pushstate close button

Tags: jquery, pushstate

I use history pushstate to load content from an other page and it works great.

I want to implement a close button for loaded pushstate content. But I have some difficulties making it work.

I want to have an empty path name when I click on close button with the title of the website.

Here the close button script:

```
if (typeof(window.history.pushState) == 'function') {
    window.history.pushState(null, refreshdocumenttitle, "");
}
```

refreshdocumenttitle is the name of the website.

This is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

```
var pageurl = $(location).attr('href');
    if(pageurl.indexOf("http://www.") > -1) {
        var nbsuppstart = pageurl.indexOf("www.")+4;
    } else {
        var nbsuppstart = pageurl.indexOf("//")+2;
    }
var nbsuppend = pageurl.indexOf(".com/");
var pagetitle = pageurl.substring(nbsuppstart,nbsuppend);

if (typeof(window.history.pushState) == 'function') {
    var stateObj = {
            title: pagetitle,
            url: '/',
            };
    window.history.pushState(stateObj,title,'/');
    document.title = pagetitle;     
}
```